# ¿Como guardar un PDF generado con DOMPDF en un servidor FTP o en un servidor local?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, dompdf

Desarrollando un sitio para mi empresa, se desarrolló un sitio que se exporta a PDF usando DOMPDF, siendo la única dificultad el guardarlo en los servidores de la empresa, o en dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive o una carpeta FTP.
¿Cómo puedo hacer esto usando PHP, mysql y javascript?

Acá el contenido del index:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Formulario de Visita</title>
        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group" id="section-to-print">
            <div class="container">

                <form class="well form-horizontal"  method="post" id="in.php">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend><img src="img/1.png" width="auto" height="65" alt="Imagen Electrónica" /></legend>
             <!-- Información Formulario -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información del Formulario</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre y dirección del Cliente</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-7">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
                                    <select name="empresa" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                      <option value=" ">Seleccione el cliente de esta lista</option>

                                      <?php
                                       $consulta=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clientes");
                                       while($dato=mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){

                                      ?>
                                        <option><?php echo $dato["Nombre"].', '.$dato["direccion"]; ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                      }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            <!-- Información Entrada -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Entrada</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input name="fechaent" class="form-control" type="date">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input class="hentrada" id="event_start_time" name="event[start_time]" type="time" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Técnico</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                    <input name="tecnico" placeholder="Correo del Técnico" class="form-control" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <!-- Información Salida -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Información - Salida</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer col-lg-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <input class="hsalida" id="event_start_time" name="event[end_time]" type="time" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Razón de la Visita</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="razonvisita" placeholder="Describa el objetivo del cliente con su visita acá"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Trabajo Realizado</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="trabajorealizado" placeholder="Describa el trabajo que realizó durante la visita."></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Comentarios</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="comentarios" placeholder=""></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 1</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                    <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma1"></script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 2</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                    <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma2"></script>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="print" action="print_pdf.php" name="crear"> Enviar (PDF) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name='submit' value='submit'> Enviar (XML) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
        <script src='js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

`index.php` es el sitio accesible a los usuarios, en donde introducirán la información, y a continuación, `in.php`, que genera el PDF.

```
<?php 
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
    session_start();
                    if($_POST){
                        $empresa= $_POST["empresa"];
                        $fechaent= $_POST["fechaent"];
                        $horaent= $_POST["hentrada"];
                        $tecnico= $_POST["tecnico"];
                        $horasal= $_POST["hsalida"];
                        $rvisita= $_POST["razonvisita"];
                        $comentarios= $_POST["comentarios"];
                        $trabajor= $_POST["trabajorealizado"];
                    }
                    $codigoHTML='
                              <!DOCTYPE html>
                              <html lang="es">
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                                    <title>Formulario de Visita</title>
                                    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css"> 
                                     <style>
                                       #wrap { margin:10px auto; width:600px; font-family:sans-serif; color:#000000; cursor:default; background-color:#eee;}
                                       h1 { font-size:40px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:10px; text-shadow:0 0 3px #ddd; }
                                       h2 { font-size:15px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:10px; }
                                       h3 { font-size:20px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:10px; text-shadow:0 0 3px #ddd; }
                                       pre {background-color:#eee; font-family:Arial; margin-left:50px; margin-right:50px;}
                                       p.demo { background-color:orange; width:100px; margin:10px 0; font-family:Arial; }
                                     </style>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="wrap">
                                                    <legend><img src="img/1.png" width="auto" height="65" alt="Imagen Electrónica" /></legend>
                                         <hr>           
                                         <!-- Información Formulario -->
                                                    <h3>Información del Formulario</h3>
                                                    <pre style="white-space:normal">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                            <form>
                                                            <b>Nombre de la Empresa: </b>
                                                            <br>'
                                                            ;$codigoHTML.=''."$empresa".'';$codigoHTML.=' 
                                                            </form>

                                                  </div>
                                                  </pre>
                                        <hr>

                                      <!-- Información Entrada -->
                                  <h3>Información Entrada</h3>
                                      <pre style="white-space:normal">  
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Fecha de Entrada:&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$fechaent".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                                                <br>
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Hora de Entrada:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$horaent".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                                                <br>
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Tecnico asignado:&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$tecnico".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                    </pre>  
                                    <hr>

              <!-- Información Salida -->
                              <h3>Información Salida</h3>
                              <pre style="white-space:normal">  
                              <div class="form-group">
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Hora de Salida:&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$horasal".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                                                <br>
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Razón de la Visita:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$rvisita".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                                                <br>
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Trabajo Realizado:&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$trabajor".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                                                <br>
                                                                <form>
                                                                <b>Comentarios:&nbsp;</b>';$codigoHTML.=''."$comentarios".'';$codigoHTML.='
                                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 1</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                          <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma1"></script>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Firma 2</label>
                                  <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer col-lg-3">
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span>
                                          <script src="js/sign.js" name="firma2"></script>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                                    </pre>


                              <script src="js/index.js"></script>
                          </fieldset>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.container -->
              <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js"></script>
              <script src="js/index.js"></script>
          </body>
        </html>';
$codigoHTML=utf8_decode($codigoHTML);
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigoHTML);
ini_set("memory_limit","128M");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream($tecnico."-".$fechaent.".pdf");
?>
```

Con `$dompdf->stream($tecnico."-".$fechaent.".pdf");` se genera el PDF, pero, ¿dónde puedo especificar la ubicación del archivo -en caso de que se decida guardar todo en el servidor local, - o la dirección FTP?

**Actualización**

Con estas lineas de código, logré generar un PDF, sin embargo, es un PDF vacio de 0 KB.

```
$dompdf->render();
$pdf=$dompdf->stream($tecnico."-".$fechaent.".pdf");
file_put_contents("forms/", $pdf);
```

¿qué hago mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no recuerdo mal, tienes la siguiente funcion disponible:

```
//Donde guardar el documento
$rutaGuardado = "\\ruta\Donde\Guardar\\Adjunto\";

//Nombre del Documento.
$nombreArchivo = $tecnico."-".$fechaent.".pdf";

//Renderiza el archivo primero
$dompdf->render();

//Guardalo en una variable
$output = $dompdf->output();

file_put_contents( $rutaGuardado.$nombreArchivo, $output);

// Una vez lo guardes en local lo puedes subir o enviar a un ftp.
```

Asegúrate que tienes permisos para escribir en el directorio, dónde guardarás los documentos.

Nota:
Modificar los permisos del directorio:

- Linux:

  chmod 777 -R ../forms/
- Windows:
  Botón derecho sobre el directorio, añadir el usuario Todos o everyone y marcar el checkbox "Control Total".

en caso de ser linux chmod 777 -R forms/

Comment: Entonces, sería así?
`$nombreArchivo = $tecnico."-".$fechaent.".pdf";
$rutaGuardado = "\\forms";
file_put_contents( $rutaGuardado.$nombreArchivo, $dompdf->output());`

Comment: La carpeta en donde quiero guardar el documento se llama "forms". Intenté así como te comenté, pero no me funciona.

Comment: stream vuelca el contenido al explorador, comenta esa linea y deja solo el output.

Comment: Gracias, tu solución funcionó de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

porque pones la barra invertida "\"? normalmente para acceder a un directorio son las barras normales `/ruta1/ruta2/arcvhivo.pdf`

Por otro lado a mi me sale este error :

> file_put_contents(/img/COTIZACION-LA-000000011.pdf): failed to open
>   stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in
>   /Controllers/Cotizaciones/ReportePdf.php line 1223

como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por favor quita la pregunta, ya que la colocaste en el sitio de respuestas.